# Preserving trailing spaces while copying and pasting code in RStudio

Tags: r, formatting, editor, rstudio, code-formatting

I want to copy and past some code in RStudio Version 0.99.834 with some special format. See below MWE.

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)


lm.D9 <- 
        lm(
          formula=weight ~ group
          )
lm.D90 <- 
          lm(
            formula =weight ~ group - 1
            ) # omitting intercept
```

Now if I copy the following code

```
lm.D9 <- 
        lm(
          formula=weight ~ group
          )
lm.D90 <- 
          lm(
            formula =weight ~ group - 1
            ) # omitting intercept
```

into `RStudio Version 0.99.834` it gives the following output

```
   lm.D9 <- 
      lm(
        formula=weight ~ group
      )
    lm.D90 <- 
      lm(
        formula =weight ~ group - 1
      ) # omitting intercept
```

which have different formatting than its source. I wonder how to preserve trailing spaces while coping and pasting code in RStudio Version 0.99.834.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Tools > Global Options... > Code Editing`

Uncheck `Auto-indent code after paste`

Comment: Thanks @Pascal for your answer. Wonder if there is any ShortCut key for this. My computer is crashing while opening `Global Options`.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Rstudio options in **Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Auto-indent code after paste**